# Prove that the power set of $\aleph_0$ =$2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

I wanted to prove that the  $\wp(A)$=$2^{|A|}$ but for $A$ is infinite. I have done this using mathematical induction. However, I was told that this only holds for a finite $A$ and that I must use another method if I was to show that the proof holds for an infinite case e.g. when  $A=\aleph_0$

Thanks

Comment: I dont see why induction wouldnt work.  Induction applies to an arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$, so it is a countably infinite by definition.  So if you can show $P(A)=2^n$ for all countably infinite numbers then whats the problem?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: What? All power sets are either finite or uncountably infinite. If you prove that $P(A)=2^n$ for all $A$ with $|A|=n \in \mathbb{N}$, then you've only proved it for finite sets, since finite sets are precisely those whose cardinalities are natural numbers.

Comment: I thought it would suffice too, but my lecturer said that this wasn't the case.

Comment: Thats not what I said, Clive. The variable $n$ is countable... infinite or finite.  If you can inductively show that $P(A)=2^n$ for any arbitrary $n\in \Bbb N$ then where is the fault?

Comment: All natural numbers $n$ (considered as sets) are finite, so the variable $n$ is not countably infinite. And even if it were, how would you extend this to *uncountably* infinite sets $A$? The statement $\mathcal{P}(A)=2^{|A|}$ is true for all sets, whether they're finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite.

Comment: P.S. Proving a statement $P(n)$ is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ does not prove that $P(\mathbb{N})$ is true. For example "$n$ is finite" is true for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but is false for $n=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Touche on that last bit.  Nevertheless regarding the cardinalities of power sets, are we not speaking in terms of definition?

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum: Definition of what? Cardinal exponentials are defined in terms of cardinalities of function sets (see the comments under my answer below). It's easier to work directly with the definition of cardinal exponentiation in this case.

Comment: Yes, you brought up definition in a comment to your answer.  It seems to me that what we are to prove is just a special case of definition.

Comment: Almost. The only part which isn't just the definition is checking that $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is in bijection with a set whose cardinality is an appropriate function set.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Consider the following function
$$
F:\mathcal{P}(A)\rightarrow 2^\mathbb{N}\\
F(X)=f_X
$$
Where $f_X$ is the characteristic function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Find a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and the set of all functions $A \to \{ 0, 1 \}$.

Comment: Isn't that to show that $2^{\aleph_0}= c$?

Comment: @Maths: No. Cardinal exponentiation is defined by declaring $\kappa^{\lambda}$ to be the cardinality of the set of functions $\lambda \to \kappa$, or equivalently the set of functions $X \to Y$ where $|X|=\lambda$ and $|Y|=\kappa$. So to prove $|\mathcal{P}(A)|=2^{|A|}$, it suffices to find a bijection between $\mathcal{P}(A)$ and the set of all functions $A \to \{ 0,1 \}$.

Comment: What?  A bijection from $A$ where $|A|=\aleph_0$ to the set $\{0,1\}$?  Am I reading you right?

Comment: That was a typo, which I've fixed ;) Also worth noting (since countability keeps coming up) that the OP wants to prove this for all $A$, not just countable $A$.